# First look on AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to learn AngularJS and the first example I have tried does not work. Why? Here is the HTML:

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>    
</head>``
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div>Hello, {{userGroup.name}}!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the javascript (`app.js` file) code:

```
var MainCtrl = function ($scope) {
   $scope.userGroup = {
      name: "Kirill Kuts"
   };
}
```

Comment: What is the error? and what version of angular?

Comment: I don't think your HTML is valid, it has `` in it between </head> and <body>. Beyond that, we'd need to see the error message or some description of "does not work" in order to answer.

Comment: Most probably you're using a recent AngularJS version. New versions does not support controller definitions this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I would start by rewriting your controller.  From AngularJS 1.3 onwards global controllers are disabled, refer:

   - https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/g3_v1_3/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-13

> $controller: disable using global controller constructors (3f2232b5)

2. Register a new angular module - with a name.

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
   $scope.userGroup = {
      name: "Kirill Kuts"
   };
});
```

3. update `ng-app` directive

---

Here is a working **demo** - http://jsbin.com/mufifukuvu/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: thank u guys, looks like that's stupid mistake. yeah, the lesson I watched is 1 year old